# Where do I get the 'She Blinded Me With Science' Cassette Tape?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Been looking all over Afghanistan for the tape so I can play it while hunting Skull Face.  Can't seem to have the tape or run into the tape yet.

Does anyone know where to get the "She Blinded me with science" cassette tape?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find it in "Wialo Village, NE Guard Post"

### The rest of them:

---

- Scouting Barren Lands / By default
- Journey to Point C-5 / By default
- Sands / By default
- Dreamt of an Eclipse / By default
- Afghanistan's a Big Place / By default
- MGO Trailer Music / By default
- Richard Wagner: "Ride of the Valkyries" from The Valkyrie -ACT III- (excerpt) / By default
- Heavens Divide / During Mission 30, on the elevator just before you reach Skull Face
- Koi no Yokushiryoku (Love Deterrence) / In Da Ghwandai Khar, in the building where you find Miller during Mission 01
- Gloria / Nova Braga Airport, inside a building on the airport's eastern side
- Kids in America / Da Shago Kallai, outside the main building
- Rebel Yell - 1999 Digital Remaster / Mountain Relay Base, just to the west of the bridge
- The Final Countdown / Qarya Sakhra Ee, inside a small building on the eastern side of the village
- Nitrogen / Serak Power Plant, inside the northernmost building
- Take On Me / Yakho Oboo Outpost, inside a room in the western wing of the outpost
- Ride A White Horse / Lamar Khaate Palace, North Guard Post
- Maneater / Lamar Khaate Palace, under the tent canopy in front of the palace
- A Phantom Pain / Wakh Sind Barracks, inside one of the huts to the northeast
- Only Time Will Tell / Eastern Communications Post
- Behind the Drapery / Da Wialo Kallai
- Love Will Tear Us Apart / Afghanistan Central Base Camp
- All the Sun Touches / Munoko ya Nioka Station
- True / Kungenga Mine
- Take The D.W. / Da Smasai Laman, under a canopy close to the amphitheater
- Friday I'm In Love / Lufwa Valley, inside the mansion
- Midnight Mirage / Bampeve Plantation, inside the northernmost building
- Dancing With Tears In My Eyes / Ditadi Abandoned Village, beneath the canopy at the foot of the rock peak
- The Tangerine / Spugmay Keep, East Guard Post
- Planet Scape / Sakhra Ee Village, South Guard Post
- How 'bout them zombies ey? / Bwala ya Masa, inside the easternmost building
- Snake Eater / Munoko ya Nioka Station, West Guard Post
- 204836 / Kungenga Mine, SW Guard Post
- You Spin Me Round (Like a Record) / Lufwa Valley, NW Guard Post
- Quiet Life / Mfinda Oilfield, inside the southeastern building
- She Blinded Me With Silence / Wialo Village, NE Guard Post
- Dormant Stream / Smasai Fort, West Guard Post
- Too Shy / Kiziba Camp, inside the tent by the anti-air radar
- METAL GEAR SOLID PEACE WALKER Main Theme / In the Quarantine Platform's basement during Mission 43
- The Man Who Sold The World / Complete Mission 46
- Sins of the Father / Complete Mission 30
- Quiet's Theme / At the end of Mission 45, follow the footprints in the sand until you trigger a cutscene

---

[Taken from source](https://www.reddit.com/r/metalgearsolid/comments/3k8hdo/heres_a_list_of_all_41_music_tapes_in_the_phantom/).

Comment: It'd be worthwhile to add some of the more relevant ones, or even the whole list then provide the link as a source, to avoid link rot.

Comment: Good idea, Added them all.